# What is the image power law?

Tags: image-processing, power-law

What exactly is the image power law mentioned at page 15 in [here:](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/presentations/0208Gist.pdf)

[image]

Is it related to [Gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) or the [statistical power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) Or anything to do with [PSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) of a camera?

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/torralba/www/ne3302.pdf